Можно ли как-то передать значение переменной из js в шаблон django?
Подскажите, можно ли как-то передать значение переменной из js в шаблон django?
Проблема в том, что мне нужно передать id товара в модальное окно. Делаю это через js, через data-product-id.
Разметка такая:
<!-- products ---->
{% for product in goods %}
    ...
    <button data-product-id="product.pk">
    ...
{% endfor %}

<!-- Modal ---->
# Здесь нужно получить id товара, чтобы получить конкретно его данные из бд

PS. Прорисовывать HTML через JS не подходит, т.к. библиотека слайдера через js ищет изображения в html, чтобы построить сам слайдер, тек. изображение и прочее. И если делать через JS, то она просто их не видит.

Чтобы бэкенд узнал что-то от фронтенда, фронтенд должен отправить http-запрос на бэкенд

Мне нужно узнать, можно ли как-то из js добавить в контекстную переменную id, или может есть еще какой-то способ. Чтобы отправить запрос на бекенд нужно делать POST или GET запрос, что перезагрузит страницу, а модальное окно нужно как раз, чтобы не перезагружая сразу увидеть.

POST или GET запрос вполне отправляется без перезагрузки, читайте про ajax

Я знаю как работает ajax. Но отправлять каждый раз запрос на сервер при "Быстрый предпросмотр" каждого товара не хотелось бы.

Ну значит придумывайте, как НЕ передавать переменную из js в шаблон django

И касательно слайдера не очень понятно, что мешает запустить слайдер *после* прорисовки HTML через JS

В этом слайдере проверяется количество изображений, который уже есть в html и после этого только она выбирает сама активную, а остальные как превьюшки. Если я добавляю изображения тоже через JS, то в момент ее проверки, она их не видит и криво все выставляет. Грубо говоря, ей нужен уже сформированный HTML. Пытался даже запустить мой скрипт до слайедра, но все равно не выходит. Работает только, если html сформирован без JS
